# If $kx+12=3k$, for how many integer values of $k$ is $x$ a positive integer?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $kx+12=3k$, for how many integer values of $k$ is $x$ a positive integer?

---

Hello!

For this problem, I first solved for $x$ in terms of $k$, giving,
$$x = \frac{3k-12}{k}.$$
Now, we want to find all values of $k$ such that what we got above is an integer. Since $x$ has to be positive, we find that $k$ has to be larger than $4$. This means, that if we write it as $\frac{3k}{k}-\frac{12}{k}$, we already know that $3k/k$ is an integer, so we only have to check for $-12/k$

Also note that we already took care of the problem of $x$ being positive, since we found that $k>4$. So now, we need to find all values of $k$ such that $-12/k$ is an integer. So, is the answer simply the factors of $-12$ greater than $4$?

Comment: Yes.  The answer is two.

Comment: Must $k$ be an integer?  Must $k$ be positive?

Comment: The answer is infinite. $k$ can be any $\frac {12}m$ for any integer (positive or negative)  $m\le 2$ and not equal to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that $k$ has to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $kx+12=3k$. Then, solving the equation for $x$ gives $x=\frac{3k-12}{k}=3-\frac{12}{k}$, so in order for $k$ and $x$ to both be integers, $k$ must be a (positive or negative) divisor of $12$.

There are $12$ (positive or negative) divisors of $12$, namely $\pm1$, $\pm2$, $\pm3$, $\pm4$, $\pm6$, and $\pm12$. If $x>0$, then $3>\frac{12}{k}$, so $k$ must either be negative or greater than $4$. The number of solutions for $k$ is therefore $6+2=8$.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Notice $x$ is positive in two cases: Either $3k - 12 > 0$ and $k > 0$, which implies $k > 4$, or $3k-12<0$ and $k<0$, so $k < 0$. You've already found the solutions corresponding to the first case. The same reasoning works for the second case too.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, nowhere is it said that $k$ must be an integer.  You've concluded that $-\frac {12}k$ must be a integer but if, so $k =-\frac 5{12}$ we get that $-\frac {12}k = 5$ is an integer.

So speak now or forever hold your peace.  Is it part of the problem that $k$ must be an integer?  Is it part of the problem tat $k$ must be a positive integer?

...

Okay  Weh have $x = \frac {3k-12}k = 3- \frac {13}k$ is an an integer greater than or equal to $1$.

So $-\frac {12}k$ is an integer greater than or equal to $-2$ and so $\frac {12}k $ is and integer less than or equal to $2$.

So if $\frac {12}k = m \le 2$ where $m\in \mathbb Z$ then $k$ can be and $\{\frac {12}m| m \le 2; m \ne 2\}$.

And $x$ can be any positive integer.

If the requirement is that $k$ is an integer then $k|12$ so $k = \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,\pm 4,\pm 6,\pm 12$ and $\frac 12{k} \le 2$ so $k = 12,6,-1,-2,-3,-4,-6,-12$ and $x = 2, 1,15,9, 7,6, 5,4$.

If the requirement is that $k$ is a positive integer then $k=12,6$ and $x = 2$ or $1$.